# How to append '\n' to before '<li>' tag in Python

Tags: python

I wanna append '\n' to before < li > tag in Python. I had using replace(' ', '\n') but not ok. Can you help me?

My code:

```
<li>Product ID: 123</li><li>Material:  100%</li><li>Test: string test  </li>
```

My desire:

```
\n<li>Product ID: 123</li>\n<li>Material:  100%</li>\n<li>Test: string test  </li>
```

Comment: what have you done for this so far?

Comment: sorry, I'm using beautifulsoup to crawl data. "details = new_data.find("div", {"class" : "layout-row product-details"}).find('ul')", when i print(details), I get the above result.

Comment: have you tried `string.replace`?

Comment: @yatu yes. I had using string.replace but not ok. Maybe I am using the "replace" command which is wrong. Can you guide me?

Comment: try `s.replace('<li>', '\n<li>')`

Comment: @yatu This is my result error when I ran command "s.replace('<li>', '\n<li>')" 
http://prntscr.com/mrw45o

Comment: So `details` is `None`. If you don't have a string you cant't call string methods on that variable.

Comment: Can you show the part of the code, from retrieving the details to the line where it raises an error?

Comment: @mfrackowiak yes. this is my code http://prntscr.com/mrw9ky and this is error when I ran http://prntscr.com/mrw9tw

Comment: 1. [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) returns list if it will find anything, 2. printing BeatifulSoup tags can be misleading, because what you retrieved earlier - `details = new_data.find("div", {"class" : "layout-row product-details"}).find('ul')` was not a str - it was `Tag` instance. To replace its `str` representation, you would have to use `str(details).replace(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
str(details).replace('<li>', '\n<li>')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prepend every tag with `\n`, you could just replace all of them with the version with prefix, e.g.:

```
>>> "<li>Product ID: 123</li><li>Material:  100%</li><li>Test: string test  </li>".replace("<li>", "\n<li>")
'\n<li>Product ID: 123</li>\n<li>Material:  100%</li>\n<li>Test: string test  </li>'
```

Comment: I tried it but it reported an error like the link attached. http://prntscr.com/mrw45o

Answer (score 0):

You can add it with a +

```
x = "<li>Product ID: 123</li>\n<li>Material:  100%</li>\n<li>Test: string test  </li>"

x1 = "\n" + x 

x1
#the result will be '\n<li>Product ID: 123</li>\n<li>Material:  100%</li>\n<li>Test: string test  </li>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why replace won't work

```
details ='<li>Product ID: 123</li><li>Material:  100%</li><li>Test: string test  </li>'
details.replace('<li>', '\n<li>')
```

In case `details` might be `None` then

```
if details:
    details.replace('<li>', '\n<li>')
```

Output

```
'\n<li>Product ID: 123</li>\n<li>Material:  100%</li>\n<li>Test: string test  </li>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command works for my case.

```
str(details).replace('<li>', '\n<li>')
```

Thanks @Heyran and @mfrackowiak and you guys.